# How to read lines from a text file but exclude and include lines at once

Tags: python, terminal, grep, find, exec

I tried the following:

```
os.system("find %s -name TestFile.txt -exec grep -i 'texttofind' {} \;| grep -vi '^\s*/{2}'" % PROJECT_PATH + "Assets")
```

As a result i ve got all the lines containing 'texttofind' even if the '//' standing prior.

I need to exclude commented lines '//' (spaces and tabs can be also prior '//) - all such lines should be excluded

Comment: Why not using another `grep -v` to exclude lines matching the pattern?

Comment: can you suggest what can I use here? The problem is that inclusion (grep) and exclusion (grep -v) does not work at once in my case. I need to read only lines with specific text but excluding commented ones

Comment: Have you tried using really Python? Or just find and grep?

Comment: can you please add sample current output and expected output. @Сергей Ким